# unreachable code detected c# forms

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am creating Q+A Forms application. I get an "unreachable code detected" warning in the line "txt.AcceptsReturn = true;". I have tried using #pragma warning disable on the line, but it doesn't execute that piece of code.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication11
{
    public partial class c1l1 : Form
    {
        int cLeft = 1;
        public c1l1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox t= new TextBox();  

            t.Text = "Enter the question for Category 1, Level 1";
            String t2;
            t2 = t.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(t2);

            AddNewTextBox();

        }

        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(txt);
            txt.Top = cLeft * 25;
            txt.Left = 100; 
            txt.Text = "TextBox " + this.cLeft.ToString();
            cLeft = cLeft + 1;
            return txt;

            txt.AcceptsReturn = true;

            KeyEventArgs e;
            if (txt.Text != null && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                txt.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are returning from the method on the line above that line. it will never be reached cause you've already returned.

Comment: return keyword signals the end of the function

Comment: The intent of the function is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

you can't write any code after [`return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx) statement in C#.

```
    public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.Top = cLeft * 25;
        txt.Left = 100; 
        txt.Text = "TextBox " + this.cLeft.ToString();
        cLeft = cLeft + 1;


        txt.AcceptsReturn = true;

        KeyEventArgs e;
        if (txt.Text != null && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            txt.Visible = false;
        }

        return txt;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Anything below **return txt;** will never be executed. You'll need to figure out where you actually want to return the value of **txt**

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.Top = cLeft * 25;
        txt.Left = 100; 
        txt.Text = "TextBox " + this.cLeft.ToString();
        cLeft = cLeft + 1;
        return txt;    //Everything below this line will never get executed

        txt.AcceptsReturn = true;

        KeyEventArgs e;
        if (txt.Text != null && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            txt.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, "unreachable code detected" is nothing but the code will never get executed, so if you see your code, you are trying to return the value in the function before the lines which are below return statement gets executed. So check your requirement and on the basis of that place the return statement in the function, that will resolve your issue.

Let me know if you need further help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have code written after the return block which the static code analyser can see will never be reached.

It is likely that you have misplaced your return statement - Any decent IDE will highlight this as it is easy to check